# Logo in Nav Bar Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationbar, titleview

I am trying to display my logo in my Navigation Bar but I can't get it to fit all the different sizes of phones. I can get it to fit one and it looks terrible on another. This is the closest Ive gotten to it looking good at all. Does anyone see how I could make this look better?

```
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WTB_LOGO"];
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 225, 115);

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 205, 115);
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[headerView addSubview:imgView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;
```

Comment: Do you want your image to appear on every ViewController as a part of navigation bar, or just on one ViewController? Do you want it to be resized or just stay in centre as it is?

Comment: Just the one ViewController. Just one size and stay centered. If I make it fit for iPhone 6 it is too far to the right on iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem your image is not centred properly within headerView. If image is all you want just don't use header at all, titleView is centred automatically.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
```

If you have a back button it will push the image View. Here's how it looks:
[image]
[image]

So you have to make your image a little smaller.

Comment: Ok so that made all the different sizes look the same which is great. But the image is still pushed to the right a bit. I have a bar button on the top left corner, could that be pushing it to the right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it like:

```
...
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 225, 115);

...

// same frame with the headerview
imgView.frame = headerView.frame;
// Note: should be `imgView.frame = headerView.frame;`
//       `imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 225, 115);` is different
//
// this also work if you are supporting multi-orientation
//
// or simply assign the imageView directly 
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
// but the width is kinda broad `225` it will probably be push if you insert UIBarButtonItem to left/right
```

Since you are using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` it will automatically scale itself to fit the frame.

if ever you needed to rescale the image here is a code for it.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Hope this helped you. Cheers! :)

Comment: Ok so that made all the different sizes look the same which is great. But the image is still pushed to the right a bit. I have a bar button on the top left corner, could that be pushing it to the right?

Comment: @KeatonCarlSwoboda, Haha.. Exactly what i added to my answer. please check my added comment.

Comment: Ok the rescaling code kinda confuses me. When I call it what will I put as the CGSize?

Comment: @KeatonCarlSwoboda: the size of the view where you want to place it. `imgView.frame.size` for example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why just not simply try this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
```

Or I'm missing anything?

Comment: The logo is too big. When I do it like that it is too big.

Comment: This is wrong, you will miss the `contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` the image will display at its original scale/size.

Comment: Understood. So what're you doing by using subview should be a way but you may try to set width and height in CGRectMake tied with detected screen size. As I'm on the go now, i can't post the code now. I'll do once I get back.